# Yahoo! Webanalytics on Intranet

Tags: analytics, web-analytics, yahoo-analytics

how is Yahoo! webanalytics to be used in a intranet scenario??

Google Analytics needs internet connection to reach the ga.js or alternatively Urchin (licensed) can be used if leaving intranet is not an option.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Analytics has the same needs of Google Analytics. They are pretty similar to one another except for the reporting capabilities.

Yahoo is better in most of the cases has more details.

If you need something which didnt need internet access you should look at http://piwik.org/ which is a open source webanalytics solution completly hosted on your web server.

Claudio.